# Find Name of person in a city with Maximum age

Tags: sql

Here the following Query will give the result for Average Age and number of residents in a City. Group BY applied on City and Aggregated functions on residents as Count and Age as AVG.

```
select city, count(*) as residents, avg(age) as AverageAge
from people
group by city
```

Similarly I want the Name of the Resident in a City With Maximum Age

```
select city, name, max(age) as AverageAge
from people
group by city
```

But this query is not working as **name** is not there in the Group By clause and neither used as a Aggregated function

Can you please help me in this.

Answer (score 3):

Not the cleanest way, but you can do:

```
SELECT P1.*
FROM People P1
JOIN
(
  SELECT City, MAX(Age) AS Age
  FROM People
  GROUP BY City
) P2 ON P1.Age = P2.Age AND P1.City = P2.City
```

Comment: Looks perfectly clean to me; that's the way I'd do it.  There might be a way using OLAP functions of doing it differently, but they're not crucial to this case.  Note that if there are three people in Whoville all with age 102, then three rows will be generated for Whoville; that's not a defect in the query but the correct answer.  If there's a criterion for choosing between the twins born on the same day, then that needs to be documented in the query specification.  One might ask why the database records Age instead of Date of Birth; Ages change continually, but Dates of Birth don't.

Comment: Joachim's solution looks slightly faster to me, although I think it's negliable (see Execution Plan for both at this edited version of his SQL fiddle) - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/57b18/2

Comment: @AaronNewton Good point on the query plans, I'm ashamed to say I didn't even look at them. Added a better query to my post.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: When taking execution plans into account, the most performant query I can figure out seems to be the one below; it also seems to give the result that makes the most sense, if there are multiple people of the same (highest) age, they will all be selected;

```
SELECT P1.* 
FROM people p1
LEFT JOIN people p2
  ON p1.city=p2.city AND p1.age < p2.age
WHERE p2.age IS NULL
```

Basically it'll use a simple left join to get all people that don't have anyone older in the same town.

Otherwise, the simplest to read "general" solution would be using a simple subquery to find the max age of anyone in the town and list people in the city of that age. If several people are of the same (highest) age, it will instead return a random one of them;

```
SELECT city, name, age
FROM people
WHERE age = (SELECT MAX(age) FROM people p WHERE p.city=people.city)
GROUP BY city;
```

I added the first query to Aaron's SQLfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f2d9/1), as you can see the first query in this post is the only one of the three without a temporary or filesort.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select city, name, max(age) as AverageAge
from people
group by city, name
```

sql group by query requires all the column names present in the select

Answer (score 0):

You need a sub query, its a very useful technique sutable for a wide range of solutions. When they are needed they are the only effective solution. I  always go to this page http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html when I have forgotten the exact synatax I need (worth bookmarking as its not page 1 on google for sub query which it has been in the past) you want the "TOP n records per group" section. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Definition of "maximum age" : there is no individual (in the same city) with a higher age

```
SELECT pp.*
FROM people pp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM people px
  WHERE px.city = pp.city
  AND px.age > pp.age
  )
  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the easiest way to do it in my opinion:

```
SELECT P.city, P.name, P.age as AverageAge
FROM people P
WHERE P.age = (SELECT MAX(age)
               FROM people.P2));
```